# Typed tests with Google Test show a warning in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, warnings, googletest

I am trying to learn to use Google Tests, so I have this template class for which I want to used typed tests.

This is the tests file that shows a warning:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gtest/gtest-typed-test.h"
#include "../Laborator/DynamicVector.hpp"

template <typename ELEM_T>
class DynamicVectorTest : public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    typedef DynamicVector<ELEM_T> Vector;
};

#if GTEST_HAS_TYPED_TEST

typedef ::testing::Types < char, int, short > Implementations;

TYPED_TEST_CASE(DynamicVectorTest, Implementations); // underlined with green

TYPED_TEST(DynamicVectorTest, Implementations)
{
    TypeParam value{};
    typename TestFixture::Vector vec;
    EXPECT_EQ(vec.getSize(), 0);
    vec.addElement(value);
    EXPECT_EQ(vec.getSize(), 1);
}

#endif // GTEST_HAS_TYPED_TEST
```

I have successfully compiled my tests, and they all ran and passed.
When hovering over the line, visual studio says: `"Function definition for 'TYPED_TEST_CASE' not found."`, however when I click `"Go to definition"` it successfully takes me inside `"gtest-typed-test.h"`

Do you have any idea what I could do about this? I tried manually including the header, although it is included inside `gtest-all.cc` and should be visible.

Picture:

[image: Warning]

Comment: Its probably an intellisense bug. There are cases where intellisense will produce false positives.

Comment: I see, so is there any way to remove just this one particular warning?

Comment: You may want to ask Microsoft.